# How change the ISO and Where is hreflang configured into Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7, country-codes, hreflang

I have a problem with Prestashop 1.7.5.1 with French Canadian language.

Pretashop has configure the French Canada has "qc" instead of "fr" or "fr_CA" which causing Google Search Console to not identify the proper language for indexing my pages.

My pages are showing in source:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://store.copiscan.com/qc/" hreflang="qc">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://store.copiscan.com/en/" hreflang="en-us">
```

I need to change it for "fr_CA". I check into Database and not found any value associated to "hreflang" configuration.

Here are my languages installed into Prestashop:
[image: Languages Configurations]

When i try to modify into Language and modify the ISO code, i get an error 500;
[image: Error after modify the language ISO codes]

Answer (score 0):

I was resolving it by modify directly into the Database under `ps_lang` table and change it directly there. The store seem's to accept it very well.

[image: r]